# How to match or replace a pattern of two appearances of one statement in RegEx?

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like bellow:

***Ryan, Ryan needs to find his papers.***

I want to change the pattern of

```
(sth), (sth)
```

to

```
(sth)
```

So, it doesn't necessarily need to be `Ryan`, it could be any other name. And the output should look like this:

```php
Ryan needs to find his papers.
```

So, basically this code but a variable instead of Ryan.

```php
preg_replace("/(Ryan), (Ryan)/","/(Ryan)/",$text);
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. This site is not a code-writing service, you are expected to show some sort of reasonable effort here first of all. We can help you try and figure out what went wrong with your attempt, but we are not here to just do your work for you.

Comment: I think you are looking for `preg_replace('/(\w+),\h+\1/', "$1", $text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
preg_replace('/\b(\p{L}+)(?:,\s*\1)+\b/u', '$1',$text)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fdy0kX/1) and [PHP proof](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLKzU5I1@hoCg1Pb4otSAnMTlVQ10/JkkjpqDap1ZbU8PeSiemWCvGUFM7Jkm/VF1HQV3FEEQGVSbm6SiASIW81NSUYoWSfIW0zLwUhYzMYoWCxILUomJ1Tev//wE).

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}+                   any character letter (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```